# Upgraded Google Console VM type from "Micro" to "Small" Now Website Showing "Apache2 Debian Default Page". What to do?

Tags: wordpress, apache2, virtual-machine, bitnami, google-console-developer

I was upgraded my VM Instance Machine Type From "Mirco" to "Small", I thought this will speed up my website. But after saving it. My wordpress website now showing "Apache2 Debian Default Page"

[Website Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv9bo.png)

I cant able to login to my (Bitnami) Wordpress Admin page too.
Everything stops suddenly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

it seems you installed the Apache2 system's service in the machine and it got started at boot time. That's why the Bitnami's Apache service can't be started because other service is already running in the 80 port. In order to stop and disable it, please run these commands

```
sudo service apache2 stop
sudo service apache2 disable
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh start apache
```

You can find more information here:

https://community.bitnami.com/t/lightsail-restart-of-server-now-loads-the-apache2-start-page-instead-of-website/58492/3?u=jota

Happy to help!